# Explore command causing errors

Tags: macvim, netrw

I open vim and then use the command :Explore. Then I got these errors:

```
Error detected while processing function netrw#Explore..netrw#LocalBrowseCheck..<SNR>16_NetrwBrowse..<SNR>16_NetrwGetBuffer..<SNR>16_NetrwEnew..<SNR>16_NetrwOptionRestore:
line   66:
E341: Internal error: lalloc(0, )
Pattern not found: @$
Error detected while processing function netrw#Explore..netrw#LocalBrowseCheck..<SNR>16_NetrwBrowse..<SNR>16_PerformListing..<SNR>16_NetrwOptionRestore:
line   66:
E341: Internal error: lalloc(0, )

Error detected while processing function netrw#Explore:
line  501:
E341: Internal error: lalloc(0, )
line  502:
E341: Internal error: lalloc(0, )
```

After I type Enter and I am able to go to the Explore.

I have no idea what they mean. Should I be worried? What can I do to stop them?

I am on Mac OS X and using vim 7.4.

Comment: E341 is an internal error according to `:h E341`. Try deleting and reinstalling MacVim and see if it goes away.

Comment: It could also be a bug in Vim, MacVim, netrw, or a combination thereof. I tried looking up what `NetrwOptionRestore` does to try and see if there may be a workaround, but netrw is such a mess that I gave up >_<